# Add context menu for file passing multiple parameters to target

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, context-menu

I would like to use an AI subtitles sync program ([Alass](https://github.com/kaegi/alass)). This is very simple in Linux/bash but I was trying for a way to achieve this using Windows and the context menu. So here my requirement:

- make the context menu appear when two files are selected AND one of the two files is .srt
- Given I would select two files in no particular order, the first (%1) would always need to be the video one (mkv/mp4/avi/etc)
- The second (%2) would always need to be the .srt
- the third can a static out.srt created in the very same folder where %1 and %2 live

Essentially the user action would be:

- Select video and subtitles while pressing CTRL
- right click
- select "Sync sub"
- The "C:\program files\alass.bat %1 %2 out.srt" is called
- Alass is run and saves on the path where %1 and %2 live

Currently using this:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.srt\shell\Alass

command=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /C "Start "" /D "%V" "C:\Program Files\Alass\alass.bat" \"%1\" \"%2\" alassout.srt"
```

But I get a "The app does not have an app associated.... error message" plus the context menu appears only if the .srt only is selected

What I would need help with is:

- How to I make a .srt extension always be passed as %2 (perhaps a modification of the .bat is needed for this to identify .srt and whatever video in whatever order they are passed?)
- How do I make the context menu appear if one of the two files is .srt
- What do I need to pass to the Context command to make it save in the very same folder where %1 and %2 live?

Thank you!